# Probability theory on equality of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I'm taking a statistics course and I am having trouble getting my head around this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

On the probability space $([0,1],B,m)$, where m denotes Lebesgue measure on the unit interval, let X : $x  →  2x^2 + 1$ be a random variable. Give two examples of random variables $Y : [0,1] →R$ such that Y is not almost surely equal to X, but Y equals X in distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to find a measure-preserving bijection $f$ on $[0,1]$ and then let $Y:x \to 2f(x)^2+1$

As an example, consider $f(x)=1-x$.  Then $Y:x \to 2(1-x)^2+1=2x^2 -4x+3$ will have the same distribution as $X$ but almost never be equal to $X$

You can find another